# SQL Server 2016 express install error: attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, sql-server-2016-express

Never thought it would be this bad when trying to install SQL Server 2016 Express Edition on Windows 10. I had both SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2012 installed and was mainly using SQL Server 2014. Then I thought I should upgrade and tried to install SQL Server 2016. I then got this error:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorised operation error.

Tried searching about this and there were suggestions about modifying registry key permissions, so I did try to modify some permission on a few SQL Server related registry keys but that didn't make any difference.

Then I kept searching and found people suggesting it might be a version clash issue so I uninstalled *all* SQL Server installations including the 2016 version (which wasn't successfully installed) and started fresh.

Now after more than two days I still cannot install a SQL Server.

Below is the part of the detailed log where the timeline matches with the timeline in the error of Windows Event Log; couldn't paste the whole detailed log as it's too long.

EDIT1: After more searching this is the actual exeption being thrown:

```
Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:     Message: 
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:     HResult : 0x84bb0001
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1211 (4bb)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:     Data: 
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       WatsonData = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE@SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FltMgr
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       HelpLink.EvtType = 0x48BB60BC@0xBB814387
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       EMBResult = Cancel
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       SQL.Setup.FailureCategory = ConfigurationFailure
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       WatsonConfigActionData = INSTALL@CONFIGNONRC@SQL_ENGINE_CORE_INST
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:       WatsonExceptionFeatureIdsActionData = System.String[]
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:     Stack: 
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String subkey, RegistryAccess requestedAccess)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.Globals.GetSqlRegistryKeyHKLM(ServiceContainer context, String key, String machineName, Boolean createIfNotFound)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.FilestreamUtils.SetFltMgrAttachWhenLoadedKey(ServiceContainer context)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.RsFxConfiguration.Install()
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.FilestreamConfiguration.Install()
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.SetupFilestream(EffectiveProperties properties)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.Install_ConfigNonRC_Prepare(EffectiveProperties properties)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.Install(ConfigActionTiming timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcb)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.PrivateConfigurationBase.Execute(ConfigActionScenario scenario, ConfigActionTiming timing, ConfigBaseAction action, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcbCurrent)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SqlFeatureConfigBase.Execute(ConfigActionScenario scenario, ConfigActionTiming timing, ConfigBaseAction action, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcbCurrent)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         Message: 
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:                 Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         HResult : 0x80070005
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:         Stack: 
(01) 2016-10-23 10:36:52 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InternalRegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String subkey, RegistryAccess requestedAccess)
```

[image: SQL 2016 install error]

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov No. I tried installing sql 2014 and it had the same error.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Can you take a look at this plz?

Answer (score 1):

I so wanted to find an answer for this but there isn't one anywhere. Not a real one, not a complete explanation.

The only thing I will be able to help with is... It has to be related to a failure to upgrade from a previous version, something lurking in the registry. Though as I say there is no answer for this, which btw I think is a disgrace on MicroSoft's part, there are an awful lot of people out there with the.

In the end to install SQL 2016 sp 1 on Windows 10 (Pro) I had to totally rebuild my PC and install on a clean Windows 8.1 worked beautifully.

I then did my Windows upgrade and SQL 2016 and all known associates run perfectly.

This may be your only answer.

Comment: I do hope rebuilding my machine is not my only answer... and if it is I wouldn't do it anyway as it's not worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955396) it may help

Check out your user account priviliges and permissions (You must have administrative permissions to setup Sql Server)

Comment: this is helpful as it gets me to find the actual exception being thrown. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Read this [Discussion](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlsetupandupgrade.aspx?ID=61d56f64-2575-4a58-9503-84579476afaf) it seems the same issue

Comment: I read that but the solution in it was moving the install folder into C drive but my install folder is already in C drive:(

Comment: Try to create a new administrator (user) and run the setup as him

Comment: According to the answer which is now deleted, using another admin account doesn't work either:(

Answer (score 0):

Using procmon.exe from Sysinternals, I saw an "ACCESS DENIED" error for this registry key: "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Edge"

The work-around that worked for me was:

1. Run regedit, change owner of the key from "SYSTEM" to "Administrator"
2. Run the SQL Server install as user Administrator

Microsoft has more info: [Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation error when you set up or update SQL Server instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/install/error-set-up-update-instances)